# Keyboard Accessibility in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have Material UI `<Popover />` in my application. As soon as I open my `<Popover />` I want to switch the focus to `<Popover />` using tab key and after closing the popover, the focus should shift back to the next element on the page, but instead the focus after completing the tab navigation on the popover shifts back to the first element on the page, so the user have to tab back again from the begining.

Is there anyway I can change the tabIndex order.

I tried setting `tabindex="1"` on the popover element but thats not helping.

Comment: did you try with `tabIndex` ? its with case-sensitive `I` in it.

Comment: yes, I have tried `tabIndex`. I applied `tabIndex= 1` on the `<div>` that contained the `<popover/>` but its not focusing on the popover.

Comment: I sort of found the reason for this problem but am still struggling to find the solution. The problem is that the `Popover` is not in the natural tabbing flow due to which when we explicitly focus on it and close it the tabbing order changes and shifts back to the first element in the page

Comment: How did u fix the issue?

Comment: It was a work around, I created a textbox with a 0 width and height so that its not visible and since textbox supports focus property unlike divs, on pressing tab I got the focus on the popover